# How to grep only the directories without any extensions in bash

Tags: grep, cut

Suppose I have a list of URL named URL.txt and I only want the directories to be output not the files or extensions such as .html, .php etc. And if it finds any extension or any file in the URL the script should move on to the next URL

```
- https://example.com/tradings/trade/trading?currency=usdt&dest=btc&tab=limit
- https://example.com/account/signup/accounts/signin/account.html
```

I want results like this:

```
- https://example.com/tradings/
- https://example.com/tradings/trade/
- https://example.com/account/
- https://example.com/account/signup/
- https://example.com/account/signup/accounts/
- https://example.com/account/signup/accounts/signin/
```

I tried this command but it won't convert into a complete URL endpoint. I want a complete URL endpoint without any extension.

`cat Urls.txt | rev | cut -d'/' -f 2  | sort -u | rev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lne '@parts = split m{/}; print join "/", @parts[0 .. $_] for 3 .. $#parts - 1' < URL.txt
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line and runs the code for each line
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to `print`
- Each line is split on `/`. We then reconnect the parts starting from 3 up to the last but one part.
- See [split](https://perldoc.pl/split) and [join](https://perldoc.pl/join) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{$NF=""}!seen[$0]++' URLS.txt
```

Explanation:

```
# Set the input field separator (FS) and the
# output fields separator (OFS) to a forward slash /
BEGIN{
    FS=OFS="/"
}

{
    # NF is a speacial variable and contains the number of fields.
    # Therefore $NF is the last field. Assign an empty to string to it
    $NF=""
}

# The variable 'seen' is an associative array, initialized on demand
# upon first usage. We are using it as a lookup to prevent printing
# the same url path twice.
!seen[$0]++
```

---

PS: Your initial command almost works, it's just the `cut` command which is wrong: You are using `cut -f2`, which would print the 2nd field, but you want `cut -f2-`, which will print the 2nd to last field:

```
rev Urls.txt  | cut -d'/' -f 2- | sort -u | rev
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna make it into a one-liner,

```
[gnm]awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="/"} (1<NF) && _==__[$(_^--NF)]++'
```

lemme help decipher this one :

> - awk errors out when u try to assign zero into NF, so (**`1 < NF`**)  is a safety check. making that shorter with $NF check has a pitfall - if the input data in last column resembles a numeric zero, that condition would inadvertently evaluate to False

> - `_` is a variable never initialized, so it would be same as 0/False.
>   I write it this way cuz my shell scripts act up
>   occasionally with that "!" mark that bash is too eager to expand

> - `__` is the seen array

> - `--NF` automatically clear out the right-most column, aka basename

> - since we've previously ensured NF >= 2, regardless of input,
>   `$(_^--NF)` evaluates to `$(0)`, since zero-to-any-non-zero power is always zero.

The rest is the same as what others have explained in detail above.